# How to identify scopes?

Tags: c++, scope

So, I'm going to start off by saying that yes, this is homework, but no I'm not just looking for answers, I'd just like some sort of understanding of how to do this problem.

The problem I'm looking for help with gives a "skeletal" C++ program:

```
int a, b, c, d;             //global variables

void Sub1();                //prototype
void Sub2();                //prototype

void main () {
    int a, b, c;
          . . .  <---------- marked point 1
}
void Sub1() {
    int b, c, d;
    . . .  <---------------- marked point 2
    while (. . .) {
       int c, d, e;
       . . . <-------------- marked point 3
    }
    . . .
}  //end Sub1
void Sub2() {
   int d, e;
   . . .  <----------------- marked point 4
}
```

The question that I am having trouble with is "Identify a scope that is nested inside another scope. For example: scope starting at line 3 and ending at line 4 is nested in scope starting at line 1 and ending at line 8."

First thing, I don't understand how the example is a correct example of such a scope.  I may be confused about what exactly a scope is, but I would think that because Sub1() and Sub2() are declared outside of any functions, they would be global, and thus their scope would be from line 1 to the end of the program.  Please help me understand why their scope is from lines 1 to 8, and maybe I can understand how to complete this problem.

Comment: Broadly and *roughly* everything between a '`{`' and a '`}`' is a scope.

Comment: I don't really understand what `line 3, 4, 1 and 8` are referring too in your question, but a scope is basically what goes in between the `{ ... }`. Outside of any curlies you have the global scope, and sometime the `{}` are omitted (a single line following an `if` statement for example).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: The code you've posted has a couple of clear examples of scope (and problems with them), and they're not what you seem to think they are, I'm afraid. You need to go back over your course notes, and if that doesn't help you need to speak to your instructor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your reference to lines numbers doesn't really make sense, but with that aside scoping is really simple:

Consider the "current" scope you're in (everything in the inner-most `{ }`) If you see a variable declared inside the curly braces with the given name then that is the one which will be used in this scope. If that name isn't found, then look at its parent scope, and so on. If there are no more curly braces then refer to the global variables.

Comment: An enclosing `{` and `}` doesn't necessarily denote a scope. Name lookup is an independent concept and not the definition of a scope.

Comment: The instructions regarding the line numbers were from the instructor.  I guess I'll speak to her about this to see if there was a misprint or something.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that "The scope starting at line 14 and ending at line 15 (the contents of the while loop) is nested inside of the scope starting at line 11 and ending at line 17 (the contents of the function Sub1( ).)"